# Having an issue with displaying a map marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I do not know what is wrong with my code for displaying a map marker for my address.  I have looked on the google development site as well as blogs and stack overflow posts but seem to not be able to understand it or for some reason can not effectively implement it into my code.    I want a marker to display for an address on a map, that when clicked will take them to a URL for google maps of that location.

My CSS:

```
 var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 4,
   center: myLatlng,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 }
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myLatlng,
   title:"Hello World!"
 });

 // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
 marker.setMap(map);
```

My HTML:

```
  <div style="height: 277px; width: 964px; z-index; 1;"> 
     <div id="map-canvas" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: have you looked at your javascript? Chances are you are probably getting some error that will tell you exactly what's wrong. I feel like at least 5 times a day someone asks this same question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        title: "Hello World!"
    });

    marker.setMap(map);

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**EDIT**:

How do I link the marker to a URL?

```
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Visit Google!</a> "
    });


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Comment: I found the issue...."mapmargin" is wrong (duh).  There is no "mapmarin" in CSS.  I just copied it from Google developer site thinking if they put it there, than it should be good to go.

Comment: Can you post another question? OR Provide more detail?